# Wordpress dropdown menu doesnt work in IE

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

Im developing a website for a customer in Wordpress. The website [www.daanen-shipping.nl](http://www.daanen-shipping.nl) has a dropdown menu which is working fine in FF/ Chrome and Safari but not in IE. The customer is useing IE 9. Apparently this is a common problem for many people. Compatibility view doesn't seem to be the problem.

Im kinda new in CSS and Javascript so i have no idea where to begin. I did hours of research with nu results. Hopefully there is someone that can help me.

Menu CSS:

```
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 180px;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li:hover a, #menu ul li.current-menu-item a, #menu ul li.current-menu-parent a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: #fff 3px solid;
    padding: 4px 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li:hover a {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#menu ul li.current-menu-item ul.sub-menu li a {
    color: #7b7b7b;
}
#menu ul li ul.sub-menu li, #menu ul li ul.sub-menu li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu ul li ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #EBEBEB;
    border: #ddd 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 0 2px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu ul li ul.sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
}
#menu ul li ul.sub-menu li a {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0px;
    color: #7b7b7b;
}
```

If there is something else i need to post to be more clear, please let me know and ill work on it.
Thanks in advance!

William.

Comment: can you please provide link to the site ?

Comment: Anyone there that can help me please?

Comment: Save me from throwing my mac out of the window!

Comment: I think more people will help if you throw out that Mac :P

Comment: Nah :) But seriously, i really can use some help. Working on a solution for 3 days straight >.<

Comment: There are 2 solutions provided in this link here. Try it and see if that works for you http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/web-design-html-and-css/threads/173749/css-drop-down-menu-not-working-in-i.e-7#

Comment: You can also try adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9"> as suggested by MSDN blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx

Comment: I had a look with IE9 and it looks fine. Have you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

hit f12 and make sure that the site is using IE 9 standards. If it's not switch to IE9 standards and see if that fixes it. If it does, you can add some code to your header that tells the browser 'if the user is using IE 8 use IE8 standards or, if the user is using IE 9, use IE 9 standards'. IE is 3 browsers in one (7,8, and 9) and it has a bad habit of switching to IE7 and quirks mode on some sites. Let me know if it works when you change to IE9 standards and, if it does, I'll see if I can dig up the code to add to force the standards.

Comment: See Yogesh's comment above... You can also try adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9"> as suggested by MSDN blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx